# Is there a way to debug JS that has already been executed?

Tags: javascript, logging

I work primarily in Ruby on Rails and I am wondering if there is a browser add-on or some other type of IDE that would provide a running log similar to the output produced by the rails server log. I know about the debuggers in Chrome or FireFox but they do not provide this sort of functionality. I want to notice a problem and be able to look at a log of all the steps JS took to get me there without having to put in break points and trying to recreate the problem.

Comment: Short answer : no

Comment: You'd have to add `console.log()` to every step of your JS, which would probably slow down your script. But debugging is part of the development process, you should probably get used to doing it.

Comment: Long answer: [node-debug](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-debugging-tutorial/) What exactly are you trying to measure/see?

Comment: There is a page that draws wrong 1/1000 times. I think its a timing issue. Because it is so hard to reproduce I can't just add logs as needed.

Comment: I wonder why you have code which can produce timing issues?  Are you saying that given the same input, the page sporadically encounters an error?  If thats the case, isn't your programming unstable?  If thats not the case, then surely you could log the input and exception message and find a way to recreate the problem.

Comment: I would say any code that can produce an error is unstable. 1) Not my code. Just trying to debug it. 2) What would you call an issue that only presents itself sometimes? 3) There is no exception. The issue is that the page is double rendering objects.